# Dotnet CLI SonarScanner is failing with dotnet 8.0 image

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am facing the issue while scanning the ASP DOTNET Core 8 project using the dotnet cli global tool. The sonarscanner is working fine on Windows 10 desktop, but it failed at CI server on container of image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0`. However the same version of SonarScanner with working with another solution where that does not have the ASP.NET Core project.

SonarQube Server: Enterprise EditionVersion 10.0

Sonar Scanner: dotnet-sonarscanner 6.2.0

Error:

```
SonarScanner for MSBuild 6.2
11:53:11     Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
11:53:11     Default properties file was found at /root/.nuget/packages/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.2.0/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
11:53:11     Loading analysis properties from /root/.nuget/packages/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.2.0/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
11:53:11     sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
11:53:11     Pre-processing started.
11:53:11     Preparing working directories...
11:53:11     Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
11:53:12     06:23:12.019  06:23:11.999  Loading analysis properties from /root/.nuget/packages/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.2.0/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
11:53:12     06:23:12.019  06:23:12.019  sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
11:53:12     06:23:12.023  Updating build integration targets...
11:53:12     06:23:12.028  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.029  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/10.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.03  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/11.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.03  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/12.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.031  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/14.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.032  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/15.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.032  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.033  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/Microsoft/MSBuild/15.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.034  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/Microsoft/MSBuild/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
11:53:12     06:23:12.036  Installed SonarQube.Integration.targets to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/bin/targets
11:53:12     06:23:12.036  Creating config and output folders...
11:53:12     06:23:12.037  Creating directory: /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf
11:53:12     06:23:12.037  Creating directory: /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/out
11:53:12     06:23:12.054  Fetching server version...
11:53:12     06:23:12.056  Downloading from https://sonarqube.devtools.zsservices.com/api/server/version...
11:53:12     06:23:12.557  Response received from https://sonarqube.devtools.zsservices.com/api/server/version...
11:53:12     06:23:12.56  Checking if the server version is supported...
11:53:12     06:23:12.565  Checking validity of server license...
11:53:12     06:23:12.565  Downloading from https://sonarqube.devtools.zsservices.com/api/editions/is_valid_license...
11:53:12     06:23:12.585  Response received from https://sonarqube.devtools.zsservices.com/api/editions/is_valid_license...
11:53:12     06:23:12.658  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
11:53:12     06:23:12.666  Fetching properties for project '#########'...
11:53:12     06:23:12.667  Downloading from https://#####/api/settings/values?component=######...
11:53:12     06:23:12.699  Response received from https://######/api/settings/values?component=######...
11:53:12     06:23:12.713  Downloading from https://######/api/languages/list...
11:53:12     06:23:12.725  Response received from https://######/api/languages/list...
11:53:12     06:23:12.733  Fetching quality profile for project '######'...
11:53:12     06:23:12.733  Downloading from https://######/api/qualityprofiles/search?project=######...
11:53:12     06:23:12.774  Response received from https://######/api/qualityprofiles/search?project=######...
11:53:12     06:23:12.78  Fetching rules for quality profile '######'...
11:53:12     06:23:12.78  Downloading from https://######/api/rules/search?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&ps=500&qprofile=######&p=1...
11:53:12     06:23:12.893  Response received from https://######/api/rules/search?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&ps=500&qprofile=######&p=1...
11:53:12     06:23:12.91  Local analyzer cache: /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources
11:53:12     06:23:12.914  Writing Roslyn generated ruleset to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf/Sonar-cs.ruleset...
11:53:12     06:23:12.935  Writing Roslyn generated ruleset to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf/Sonar-cs-none.ruleset...
11:53:12     06:23:12.939  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
11:53:12     06:23:12.94  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
11:53:12     06:23:12.94  Processing plugin: csharp version 8.55.0.65544
11:53:12     06:23:12.992  Cache miss: plugin files were not found in the local cache
11:53:12     06:23:12.993  Fetching resource for plugin: csharp, version 8.55.0.65544. Resource: SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip
11:53:12     06:23:12.993  Downloading SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/0
11:53:12     06:23:12.994  Downloading file to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/0/SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip...
11:53:12     06:23:12.994  Downloading from https://######/static/csharp/SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.032  Response received from https://######/static/csharp/SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.041  Extracting files to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/0...
11:53:13     06:23:13.087  Processing plugin: vbnet version 8.55.0.65544
11:53:13     06:23:13.102  Cache miss: plugin files were not found in the local cache
11:53:13     06:23:13.102  Fetching resource for plugin: vbnet, version 8.55.0.65544. Resource: SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip
11:53:13     06:23:13.102  Downloading SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/1
11:53:13     06:23:13.102  Downloading file to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/1/SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.102  Downloading from https://######/static/vbnet/SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.114  Response received from https://######/static/vbnet/SonarAnalyzer-8.55.0.65544.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.115  Extracting files to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/1...
11:53:13     06:23:13.136  Processing plugin: securitycsharpfrontend version 10.0.0.20234
11:53:13     06:23:13.138  Cache miss: plugin files were not found in the local cache
11:53:13     06:23:13.138  Fetching resource for plugin: securitycsharpfrontend, version 10.0.0.20234. Resource: SonarAnalyzer.Security-10.0.0.20234.zip
11:53:13     06:23:13.138  Downloading SonarAnalyzer.Security-10.0.0.20234.zip to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/2
11:53:13     06:23:13.138  Downloading file to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/2/SonarAnalyzer.Security-10.0.0.20234.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.14  Downloading from https://######/static/securitycsharpfrontend/SonarAnalyzer.Security-10.0.0.20234.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.147  Response received from https://######/static/securitycsharpfrontend/SonarAnalyzer.Security-10.0.0.20234.zip...
11:53:13     06:23:13.149  Extracting files to /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/2...
11:53:13     06:23:13.17  Writing Roslyn analyzer additional file to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf/cs/SonarLint.xml...
11:53:13     06:23:13.171  Fetching quality profile for project '######'...
11:53:13     06:23:13.172  Downloading from https://######/api/qualityprofiles/search?project=######...
11:53:13     06:23:13.211  Response received from https://######/api/qualityprofiles/search?project=######...
11:53:13     06:23:13.213  Fetching rules for quality profile 'AYJ-KBq2XOwVvgx9jUmr'...
11:53:13     06:23:13.213  Downloading from https://######/api/rules/search?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&ps=500&qprofile=AYJ-KBq2XOwVvgx9jUmr&p=1...
11:53:13     06:23:13.265  Response received from https://######/api/rules/search?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&ps=500&qprofile=AYJ-KBq2XOwVvgx9jUmr&p=1...
11:53:13     06:23:13.271  Local analyzer cache: /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources
11:53:13     06:23:13.272  Writing Roslyn generated ruleset to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf/Sonar-vbnet.ruleset...
11:53:13     06:23:13.273  Writing Roslyn generated ruleset to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf/Sonar-vbnet-none.ruleset...
11:53:13     06:23:13.274  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...
11:53:13     06:23:13.274  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
11:53:13     06:23:13.274  Processing plugin: csharp version 8.55.0.65544
11:53:13     06:23:13.275  Cache hit: using plugin files from /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/0
11:53:13     06:23:13.275  Processing plugin: vbnet version 8.55.0.65544
11:53:13     06:23:13.276  Cache hit: using plugin files from /app/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/.sonarqube/resources/1
11:53:13     06:23:13.277  Writing Roslyn analyzer additional file to /app/buildagent/work/3cea31a8a2e2aa95/src/.sonarqube/conf/vbnet/SonarLint.xml...
11:53:13     06:23:13.281  Processing analysis cache
11:53:13     06:23:13.284  Incremental PR analysis: Base branch parameter was not provided.
11:53:13     06:23:13.284  Cache data is empty. A full analysis will be performed.
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
      ---> System.ArgumentException: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x1B, is an invalid character.
        at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
        at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
        at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
        at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteElementString(String localName, String ns, String value, XmlQualifiedName xsiType)
        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAnalysisConfig.Write6_AnalysisConfig(String n, String ns, AnalysisConfig o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterAnalysisConfig.Write7_AnalysisConfig(Object o)
        at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
        at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.Serializer.Write[T](T model, TextWriter writer)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.Serializer.SaveModel[T](T model, String fileName)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.AnalysisConfig.Save(String fileName)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.AnalysisConfigGenerator.GenerateFile(ProcessedArgs localSettings, BuildSettings buildSettings, Dictionary`2 additionalSettings, IDictionary`2 serverProperties, List`1 analyzersSettings, String sonarQubeVersion)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.PreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs localSettings)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.PreProcessor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 args)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.PreProcess()
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.Execute()
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Main(String[] args)
        at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: Maybe it is an issue in your ASP DOTNET project. 0x1B = ESC character.  Could you try to analyze a default ASP DOTNET project without issues?

Comment: The same project ran well when the framework switched back to dotnet 6.0 without change in command.